# GetCustomAttributes does not return value

Tags: c#, reflection, ado.net

I have defined a custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property )]
public class FieldAttribute: Attribute
{
    public FieldAttribute(string field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
    private string field;

    public string Field
    {
        get { return field; }

    }
}
```

My Class which uses the custom attribute is as below

```
[Serializable()]   
public class DocumentMaster : DomainBase
{

    [Field("DOC_CODE")]
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }


    [Field("DOC_NAME")]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }


    [Field("REMARKS")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }


   }
}
```

But when i try to get the value of the custom attribute it returns null object

```
Type typeOfT = typeof(T);
T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

PropertyInfo[] propInfo = typeOfT.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in propInfo)
{

     object[] colName = roperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FieldAttributes), false);
     /// colName has no values.
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is `FieldAttributes` a typo? should be `FieldAttribute` ? is `roperty` also a typo?

Comment: Also - what `T` are you calling it with?

Comment: Yup, typo.  Use a better name, ColumnNameAttribute for example.  Or just use Linq to SQL which does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

typo: should be `typeof(FieldAttribute)`. There is an unrelated system enum called `FieldAttributes` (in `System.Reflection`, which you have in your `using` directives, since `PropertyInfo` resolves correctly).

Also, this is easier usage (assuming the attribute doesn't allow duplicates):

```
var field = (FieldAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
          property, typeof (FieldAttribute), false);
if(field != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(field.Field);
}
```